# Scheduled datetime conversion error (SQL)

Tags: sql-server, datetime, type-conversion, scheduled-tasks, ssms

When trying to convert a datetime field to get rid of NULL's I am getting the error that the datetime cannot be converted.

This query is populating another database where the column datatype is date.

This job runs perfectly fine when not scheduled, but results in an error during the scheduled insert job.

Any ideas?

```
, (SELECT 
       CASE
          WHEN MIN([Discount Ledger].[Posting Date]) IS NOT NULL 
             THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), MIN([Discount Ledger].[Posting Date]), 121)
             ELSE '-'
       END
   FROM 
       [Wings$Discount Ledger Entry] AS "Discount Ledger" 
   LEFT JOIN 
       [Wings$Periodic Discount] AS "MixMatchHeader" ON [Discount Ledger].[Offer No_] = [MixMatchHeader].[No_]
   LEFT JOIN 
       [Wings$Periodic Discount Line] AS "MixMatch" ON [MixMatchHeader].[No_] = [MixMatch].[Offer No_]
   LEFT JOIN 
       [Wings$Item_Special Group Link] AS "Special Group" ON [MixMatch].[No_] = [Special Group].[Special Group Code]
   LEFT JOIN 
       [Wings$Store Price Group] AS "Store Price Group" ON [MixMatch].[Price Group] = [Store Price Group].[Price Group Code]
   WHERE 
       [MixMatch].[No_] = [Item Ledger].[Item No_] 
       AND [MixMatch].[Variant Code] = [Item Ledger].[Variant Code] 
       AND [Store Price Group].[Store] = [Item Ledger].[Location Code]) AS "Discount Start Date"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `ISNULL`. Since you are looking for the `MIN` date, I will use `GETDATE()` as the argument/replacement value for `NULL`. Unless your data has future dates, then `GETDATE()` should function as the `MAX` value. Unless you want the `CASE` statement to evaluate the `NULL` values as the `MIN`. In that case, you can use an empty string `''` or `'1900-01-01'` instead of `GETDATE()`.

```
, (SELECT 
CASE
WHEN
MIN([Discount Ledger].[Posting Date]) IS NOT NULL 
THEN CONVERT(varchar(50),MIN(ISNULL([Discount Ledger].[Posting Date],GETDATE())),121)
ELSE '-'
END
FROM [Wings$Discount Ledger Entry] AS "Discount Ledger" 
LEFT JOIN [Wings$Periodic Discount] AS "MixMatchHeader" ON [Discount Ledger].[Offer No_] = [MixMatchHeader].[No_]
LEFT JOIN [Wings$Periodic Discount Line] AS "MixMatch" ON [MixMatchHeader].[No_] = [MixMatch].[Offer No_]
LEFT JOIN [Wings$Item_Special Group Link] AS "Special Group" ON [MixMatch].[No_] = [Special Group].[Special Group Code]
LEFT JOIN [Wings$Store Price Group] AS "Store Price Group" ON [MixMatch].[Price Group] = [Store Price Group].[Price Group Code]
WHERE [MixMatch].[No_] = [Item Ledger].[Item No_] AND [MixMatch].[Variant Code] = [Item Ledger].[Variant Code] AND [Store Price Group].[Store] = [Item Ledger].[Location Code])
AS "Discount Start Date"
```

Comment: Hi Jacob, Thanks for the response.  My goal for this is to get rid of the NULL or '1900-01-01'.  If the date is blank, I want to display a '-' or say 'NONE', but its resulting in an out of range value.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Displayed values are often handled in the front end. Is this for a report or export to excel or something similar?

Comment: Im dumping results form this query into another SQL database and have excel directly connected to the second database.  Just annoys me to have "blank" or "1900-01-01" in the cells.